# azure developement fabric dll hell

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, windows-server-2008, azure

Hello I am trying to package and start up azure developement fabric on a windows 2008 server, I am so close yet still far. The steps I take are
1) run cspack.exe command /copyOnly to generate the .csx folder 
2) run csrun.exe commmand /LaunchBrowser to start up the developement fabric and startup the browser

the error is as follows

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'Interop.SSCE' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect
>   format.
>
> == Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = IP-0AE2B2DF\Administrator LOG:
>   DisplayName = Interop.SSCE  (Partial)
>   LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Visual
>   Studio
>   2010/Projects/MyAzureProject/src/AzureCloudService/ServiceDefinition.csx/roles/MyAzureProject.Web/approot/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\MyAzureProject\src\AzureCloudService\ServiceDefinition.csx\roles\MyAzureProject.Web\approot\bin
>   Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application
>   configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\MyAzureProject\src\AzureCloudService\ServiceDefinition.csx\roles\MyAzureProject.Web\approot\web.config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file
>   from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to
>   reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based
>   assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/dftmp/s0/deployment(98)/res/deployment(98).AzureCloudService.MyAzureProject.Web.0/aspNetTemp/aspNetTemp/root/dfbc079a/82bed8d5/Interop.SSCE.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/dftmp/s0/deployment(98)/res/deployment(98).AzureCloudService.MyAzureProject.Web.0/aspNetTemp/aspNetTemp/root/dfbc079a/82bed8d5/Interop.SSCE/Interop.SSCE.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Visual
>   Studio
>   2010/Projects/MyAzureProject/src/AzureCloudService/ServiceDefinition.csx/roles/MyAzureProject.Web/approot/bin/Interop.SSCE.DLL.
>   ERR: Failed to complete setup of
>   assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing
>   terminated.

this error happens with 2 dlls Interop.SSCE.DLL and SqlLite.dll Ive replaced all references to  SqLite dll with a 64bit version and I dont have any references anymore to Interop.SSCE.DLL since I am not using it. Manually deleting these assemblies from the location

"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 
2010\Projects\MyAzureProject\src\AzureCloudService\ServiceDefinition.csx\roles\MyAzureProject.Web\approot\bin"

solves the issue, but I dont obviously want to manually delete these everytime as I trying to automate a build process. My question is then how is the .csx folder actually generated and will this give me clues as to where these dll's are bring copied from? This is really frustrating as with the exception of those dll errors, I =m able to package the solution and startup the developement fabric with no other problems. Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I just ran across it while trying to solve the same problem. In my case, the issue was that some of my projects were set to build x86 assemblies, instead of Any CPU. The solution was:

1. Go to Build -> Configuration Manager
2. Make sure "Active solution platform" is set to "Any CPU"
3. Make sure each of the projects also has the "Platform" set to "Any CPU"
4. Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects

Check the `Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects`.
This will ensure that your web project runs in `x64` mode and will thus be able to use *Service Fabric* files.

Hope it helps...